# how to fix bug in telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

[When run through the terminal, it looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTbe7.jpg)

[Python:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0TPL.jpg)

I'm creating a delivery bot, I get errors like this. What do I need to change in order for the bot to start? I tried changing it, but the error still remains.

Comment: You installed the library?

Comment: Show code and error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Doniyor Klichev\Desktop\DeliveryBot-master\bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import  Telebot, types
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Telebot'

C:\Users\Doniyor Klichev\Desktop\DeliveryBot-master>     -  it's still not working I installed both libraries

Answer (score 3):

***It seems you didn't install the library*** to install it enter the following command to the command prompt (cmd), and enter the following command!

```
pip install telebot
```

Comment: it's still not working I installed both libraries

Comment: Can you take a screenshot when you enter the command in cmd ?

Comment: I need full cmd window when you enter (pip install) screenshot, and can you also take screenshot of error you get when do run the code from terminal and IDE (like PyCharm or vs code) after entering the command of pip install into cmd

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/jjHLxFX7/photo-2022-01-31-12-40-10.jpg
https://i.postimg.cc/hjKhf1y3/photo-2022-01-31-12-40-16.jpg
https://i.postimg.cc/fL5yXS1W/photo-2022-01-31-12-40-20.jpg https://i.postimg.cc/QCPznSv6/photo-2022-01-31-12-40-00.jpg

Comment: Here is the issue you made [**you can check it here**](https://i.postimg.cc/fL5yXS1W/photo-2022-01-31-12-40-20.jpg) , you entered the following command `pip install` and you should enter `pip install telebot` and take a new screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

from [pipy](https://pypi.org/project/telebot/)

```
pip install telebot
```

to install the library. It looks like you haven't installed it

Comment: it's still not working I installed both libraries

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Doniyor Klichev\Desktop\DeliveryBot-master\bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import  Telebot, types
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Telebot'

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install pytelegrambotapi
```

homepage: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI